# Get result when not finding User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to see if a User I just found already belongs to my Group or not.

The thing is; That if it exists it gives a `true`. If it doesn't exist it says `Couldn't find User with id=2 [WHERE "groups_users"."group_id" = ?]`. How come I don't get a `false` in that case?

```
email = params[:email]

if !email.blank?
  userExists = User.find_by_email(email)
  if userExists.blank?
    #User doesn't exist
  else
    #User does exist
    @userIsInGroup = !@group.users.find(userExists).blank?
  end
end
```

Using `@userIsInGroup = @group.users.find(userExists)` instead of an IF doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: That was suprisingly easy. It works; Make it an answer so i can upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if userExists.blank?
    #User doesn't exist
  else
    #User does exist
    @userIsInGroup = !@group.users.find(userExists).blank?
  end
```

If the record doesn't exist `ActiveRecord` returns

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with ID=number

```
@userIsInGroup = !@group.users.find_by_id(userExists).blank?
```

while `find_by_column_name` returns `nil`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want boolean value in `@userIsInGroup` if so use `include` method of [`enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-include-3F) class as following

Changed

```
@userIsInGroup = @group.users.find(userExists).blank?
```

To

```
@userIsInGroup = @group.users.include?(userExists)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could call it by using

```
if User.exists?(email: params[:email])
  do stuff
else
  don't do stuff
end
```

Comment: I need the user to exist in User and not exist in Group though. So why not save the user in a variable so I can use it later on? :)

Comment: You can, this was just an example, you can do assignment like this `userExists = User.exists?(email: params[:email]) ? User.find_by_email(email) : false`